# Devise invitable callback: undefined method `before_invitation_created'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm having trouble with the callbacks in devise_invitable - specifically, they seem to be undefined.

If I try to add:

```
before_invitation_created :set_pending_invite
```

to my user model, I get the following error

undefined method `before_invitation_created'

Is there a trick to getting the callbacks to be recognized? Do I need to add something to my controller?

I do have :invitable in my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pending_sites
rolify :role_cname => 'Group'

devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :zxcvbnable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:saml]

before_invitation_created :set_pending_invite
after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
```

Comment: except this callback other devise invitable functionality is working ?

Comment: After adding did you restart your server and if you are trying from rails console, then restart the rails console..

Comment: The server won't actually restart because of this error - if I try to restart I get: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `before_invitation_created' for #<Class:0x007fad38a991c8> (NoMethodError)

Comment: I am using the same gem without issue. Your installation of the gem is successful ?

Comment: Yes every other aspect of the gem works fine, which leads me to believe there's something wrong with my syntax or placement of the callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I looked into it, and the master branch defines those callbacks, but they're not released yet. As of this writing, the latest release is 1.5.5 from Dec 17th, 2015 and the commit with the new callbacks wasn't made until Dec 29th, 2015 (https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/commit/3834b65bf1b979a4e9c8c1ac9769ea881e350c80)

Furthermore, if you want to use the latest, you can put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise_invitable', :git => 'git@github.com:scambra/devise_invitable.git'
```